# Increase the size of a datepicker in react js Fluent-ui Northstar

Tags: css, reactjs, datepicker, microsoft-teams, fluent

How do I set the width to 100% in Fluent-ui Northstar?
width is set to 100% but not showing up

```
const getMatterTypeField = () => {

    return formFieldsMatterDueDate({

      label: "Due Date",

      id: "dueDate",

      key: "dueDate",

      name: "dueDate",

      className: "half-width-left matterDate",

      classNameControl: "createform",

      type: Datepicker,

      required: true,
      fluid: true,
      placeholder: "Select DueDate",

      styles: {width:"100%"},

      defaultSelectedDate:new Date(moment(getMattervalue.dueDate)),

      minDate: new Date(moment(getMattervalue.startDate)),

      defaultValue: moment(getMattervalue.dueDate),

      onDateChangeFn: (name, value) => setMatterInfo("dueDate", value),
      
    
    });
  };
```

return ;

Width of the datepicker is not same as textbox of the other fields in the form

Comment: Could you please try adding suffix adding !important to your width property as below:  width: 100% !important;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set the parents div of the datepicker also to 100% or whatever width you need to achieve that increase. Probably you will have to overwrite some css style

Comment: Already set div width to 100%

Comment: still trying to resolve

Comment: @Viz -  Could you please inspect the UI with Developer tool in your browser and check if your CSS is overriding or check your parent width also.